# Unity, at higher resolution (2560 x 1440) tester cannot click the navigation elements on the screen even though they are in position

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is my issue, the way my game works is that you click on the edges of the screen to navigate. This is done through an Overlay Canvas using OnPointerClick. I colored the navigation areas, and scale the canvas according to screen size and the navigation areas appear on their screen as they should. Yet they CANNOT click any of the elements for some reason. They have another monitor that works without issue. They've noted that their larger monitor is AMD. I've also confirmed that the ability to navigate in game has not been hindered. I have never had this issue (or any other testers) on 1920x1080 monitors.

I have completely exhausted what the issue can be, they cannot even navigate on a bare bones tutorial. Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated.

Here is an image of their screen and the respective clickable navigation areas.

[img][https://i.imgur.com/NVQkA8g.png[/img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7mqz.png)

Unity 2019.2.14f1

Answer (score 0):

Put a Image component without sprite, because without that, you will not detect any click. You can set the alpha to 0 after you see that working.

Also check the anchors of the navigation areas.

Comment: It is an Image on a canvas I'm afraid, the clicks are detected (I run the same version in the editor and desktop) on my 1920 x 1080, I have only had 2 people have this issue, and they both reported higher rest screens, I'm really lost here

Comment: Check the canvas scaler mode to be in  "Scale With Screen Size"